# FIXED : Delphi drawing on PlotGrid glitch? requires form resize first

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawing, firemonkey, onpaint

UPDATE...................

OK I am stupid. I was making a mistake on how I was pushing the cos wave across the screen which did not show the updates until the form changed sizes...BUT I did find something very interesting regarding the timage and bitmap sizes in an android.. see this conversation: (It is important and not documented).
[Component sizes in Delphi Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449501/component-sizes-in-delphi-android)

Origingal post .........................................

I am using fmx and delphi. I am doing my canvas drawing in the plotgrid paint event. 
In the onpaint event I am drawing a cos wave. It initially draws, subsequent calls move the wave across the canvas. I initially tied a timer with a plotgrid.repaint and nothing would happen until I resized the form and then it would operate as expected. I disabled the timer and I added a button to call plotgrid.repaint. it does calls the paint event (I see this in showmessages and the debugger).. and nothing happens. Once I resize the form then everything works as expected subsequent button calls redraw on the plotgrid.canvas.. I started with the demo sample.

any help? thanks

please note I also added comment about what makes it work.
below.

Added code below

```
procedure TMainForm.PlotGridPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
const ARect: TRectF);
begin

    // plotgrid.Frequency:=2000;

    //showmessage('plotgrid paint');

    PlotGrid.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1;                  // Set stroke thickness

//CalculateSin;                                          // Calculate and scale X and sin(X) values and save them in FPoints
// PlotGrid.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;    // Set color for sin to red
//PlotGrid.Canvas.DrawPolygon(FPoints, 1);               // Draw sin graph

// SetParams;
   CalculateCos(Radian);                                          // Calculate and scale X and cos(X) values and save them in FPoints
   PlotGrid.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;   // Set color for cos to blue
   PlotGrid.Canvas.DrawPolygon(FPoints, 1);               // Draw cos graph
end;

procedure TMainForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   plotgrid.Repaint;

end;
```

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: if I simply add mainform.width:=mainform.Width +1; into the form activate event then everything works as expected????

Comment: Ok it gets weirder,  If I leave plotgrid on the mainform anytime the mainform goes to the default width (designed width) the plotgrid on paint events stop working. e.g works width+1 but then when width dynamically set back it stops... If I put plotgrid in in a scaled layout the same tricks no longer work.